# Concrete Applications of Lattices to Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, applications, lattice-orders

The importance of lattices to algebra (or any field of mathematics really) should be fairly obvious. Specifically, we always have a complete lattice of subobjects (and a lattice of strong subobjects etc.) and a complete lattice of congruences.

However, even though I like to claim this all the time I don't actually good way to illustrate the usefulness of this theory.

> What are some concrete application of lattices to algebra?

This could be anything ranging from an alternate (better) proof of a classical theorem, to help in computing the subgroups of a finite group (if this is ever a thing, I'm only speculating here) or anything else, that you can hopefully motivate for a "classical" algebraist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many answers to this question, but one application of lattices is described in [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388588).  Quoting from the answer, "There is a deep theory of congruence lattices and what they tell us about the underlying algebras. Probably the best reference for this theory is [The Shape of Congruence Lattices](http://spot.colorado.edu/~kearnes/Papers/cong.pdf), by Kearnes and Kiss."

Another concrete application of lattices: determine properties of a group from the shape of its lattice of subgroups.  This and many other such applications are described in Roland Schmidt's [Subgroup lattices of groups](https://books.google.com/books?id=EuVadOnix5MC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Here's a simple example of this. Suppose $G$ is a group such that the lattice on the left in [this drawing](https://awwapp.com/s/f53835fa-5fde-4862-a135-6685daaaa503/) is isomorphic to the subgroup lattice of $G$, or isomorphic to an interval in the subgroup lattice of $G$. Then $G$ is not solvable.

(The same can be said of the lattice on the right in the drawing.)

It might be a worthwhile exercise to try to characterize lattices that cannot appear as intervals in subgroup lattices of finite solvable groups.

Incidentally, it is not known whether there exists a finite group that has the lattice on the right as an interval in its subgroup lattice. See [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85724/). On the other hand, it can be shown that the lattice on the left is an interval in a subgroup lattice of a finite group.

A nice survey of this application of lattices is [here](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~williamdemeo/latticetheory/Palfy-GroupsAndLattices-GStA-2001.pdf).